# Из молодежного жаргона: рофлить и троллить

Tags: жаргон

Попробовав пройти тест (https://riamo.ru/article/407179/stenit-krashej-i-forsit-mem-pojmesh-li-ty-podrostkov.xl), из пояснения к вопросу — *Рофлить* и *Троллить* это одно и то же? — не увидел существенной разницы в словах. Возник вопрос: а можно ли **троллить по-дружески**?

Answer (score 3):

Прикольный тест.

*Рофлить* — смеяться по-дружески.
Это позитивное слово.
От англ. ROFL, сокращение от *rolling on the floor*, laughing ‘*катаюсь по полу от смеха*’.
[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/рофлить](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)

*Троллить* — это негативное слово, как и тролль. Похоже на "*прикалываться с кого-то*", только жёстче. Если по-дружески, то лучше на что-то другое заменить.
Некоторые любят попускать друг друга по очереди (типа по-дружески), так как им это весело. Но ROFL является лишь следствием.

Comment: @shampar Нет-нет. Именно "*попускать*". Это тоже сленг.

Comment: Если Попускать тоже стало сленговым, то остаётся только материться, простите.

Comment: Но значение другое: http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2051637-chto-na-molodjozhnom-slenge-oznachaet-slovo-popustit.html

Comment: Я и говорю о заимствовании. Что остаётся только... Ну берёшь, допустим, из латиницы, что плохо лежит, так никто и не будет против. Но зачем родную речь поганить, выдёргивая из неё приличные слова?

Comment: Всё равно оно устаревшее. Честно говоря, даже и не знал, что существует несленговый вариант. Ещё есть жаргонное значение: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/попускать

Comment: Оно — часть церковно-славянской литературы и современной духовной культуры и в т.ч. речи.

Comment: Значение похоже на обычное: это как опустить кого-то, но в более лёгкой форме. То есть по аналогии с "*поставить вниз*", только морально (в переносном смысле).

Answer (score 1):

Я бы добавил, что "троллить" - это уже давно не подростковый сленг. Слово плотно вошло в язык и используется очень активно людьми любого возраста.

Можно ли теоретически троллить по-дружески? Можно ведь подшучивать по-дружески или прикалываться? Если мотивация не обидеть, а пошутить, то почему нет. Но все-таки в большинстве случаев это не дружеское поведение.